# I am using SqlDataReader in ASP.NET and at load_page event have as issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cnString);
    con.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from about_us", con);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (!reader.HasRows)
    {
        lblservicedesc.Text = "No Records";
        lblshortdesc.Text = "No Records";
    }
    else
    {
        reader.Read();
        lblshortdesc.Text = reader["AboutShortDescription"].ToString();
        lblservicedesc.Text = reader["ServicesDescription"].ToString();

        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **explain** what that issue is! After all: we **cannot** read your screen, nor your mind ....

Comment: Second label is returning empty although data base has values

Comment: Well, the next question would be: what the is the structure of the `about_us` table?

Comment: Make sure you spelled the field name properly including uppercase/lowercase.

Comment: @marc_s it is the about us table having descriptions in nvarchar datatype.

Comment: @jdweng i spelled it correctly

Comment: Yes - ok - but what are the **column names** ?? YOu're asking for a `ServicesDescription` - is there ??

Comment: So what happens if you **DEBUG** your code? What are you seeing? Do you get rows back from the database??

Comment: I debugged the code and it returns only first row filled the second one empty

Comment: SQL Server doesn't return queries in any particular order unless you use an Order By.  Don't assume the second row in the database is the one that is empty.  You may have an empty row in the database in a different location.

Comment: Ok @jdwenf so what if i have only one row and i wanted to assign a particular column to a label

Comment: `longDescription` , `ExperienceDescription` ,`AboutShortDescription`, `QualityDescription` , `WorkOnTimeDescription`, `OnGoingProjectsDescription` these are the ** column names ** @marc_s

Comment: You're trying to load a `ServicesDescription` - and that **DOES NOT** exist - so you're getting back an empty string .  You need to load an **existing** column !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to look like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cnString);
    con.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from about_us", con);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    lblservicedesc.Text = "No Records";
    lblshortdesc.Text = "No Records";

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        lblshortdesc.Text = reader["AboutShortDescription"].ToString();
        lblservicedesc.Text = reader["OnGoingProjectsDescription"].ToString();
    }

    reader.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

Keep in mind that if you have multiple rows, your labels are only going to show the last rows values.

Comment: still it is returning nothing @thewisegod

Comment: Do you have a column named "ServicesDescription" ?

Comment: I am having just one row and i want to assign different column to different label @thewisegod

Comment: longDescription , ExperienceDescription ,AboutShortDescription, QualityDescription , WorkOnTimeDescription, OnGoingProjectsDescription these are the column names

Comment: The problem is that you don't have a column named "ServicesDescription", if you copied my updated answer, both your labels should be populated now.

Comment: Thank u @thewisegod it is done now with your updated answer i am not having that column name.